# Application Pool in TomCat?

Tags: iis, tomcat, iis-7, tomcat6, tomcat7

IIS has concept of "Application Pool" which can isolate the applications to a specific pool. Does  Tomcat have the similiar one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the IIS concept correctly then all Tomcat applications effectively run in their own application pool and cannot access other applications.